# Camunda custom insert queries

Tags: crud, mybatis, camunda

While following this documentation and sample https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.3/real-life/how-to/#process-engine-custom-queries-custom-mybatis-queries,  could you please explain how we can  execute insert queries?  In the sample to list values they have used below method. 
commandContext.getDbSqlSession().selectList("selectTasksForRegion", region, 0, 100);

However commandContext.getDbSqlSession().insert is a protected method, therefore I'm unable to get an insert query out of it. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DbEntityManager has an
[insert](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.4/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/db/entitymanager/DbEntityManager.html#insert(org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.DbEntity))
method. The insert and update is than managed by the DbSqlSession based on the
[getPersistantState](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.4/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/db/DbEntity.html#getPersistentState())
of the DbEntity. You only have to provided the correspondig mappings which have
to be prefixed with `insert` and `update`. For example see the build-in
entities.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. so given that  I have an entity class named propsEntity if i call following code , commandContext.getDbEntityManager.update(PropsEntity.class, "updatePropsEntity", props);    and then in my mappings file i have <update id="updatePropsEntity"      >  update ${prefix} table name  , will it be correct?

Comment: It depends for example look at the [Task.xml](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/main/resources/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Task.xml#L59-L103) mapping. It has two update statements `updateTask` and `updateTaskSuspensionStateByParameters`. The first one is automatically called by the DbSqlSession if a TaskEntity is dirty on flush. The second one is explicitly called by the [TaskManager](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/persistence/entity/TaskManager.java#L164-L191).

Answer (score 0):

in the underlying MyBatis SqlSession object, you will find what you need. You just have to navigate one level deeper: `commandContext.getDbSqlSession().getSqlSession()`

The entire line looks like this:

```
commandContext.getDbSqlSession().getSqlSession().insert("insertStuff", stuff);
```

With `insertStuff` being the name of your custom query and `stuff` being the parameter object for that query.